Finding Exceptions Without try/catch in Flutter
Some One Asked Me How Find Exception Error Without Using Try Catch Method After RND on That I Got These Answer
In Flutter, there is no direct way to find an exception without using a try-catch block. The try-catch block is the standard mechanism for handling and inspecting exceptions in Dart, and it’s essential for error handling in Flutter applications.

ErrorBuilder: When using Image widgets, you can specify an errorBuilder callback to handle errors when loading images. This callback receives the exception and stack trace as arguments, allowing you to inspect and handle the error programmatically

Image.asset(
  'assets/images/image.png',
  width: 90,
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print(exception);
    // Handle the error or return a fallback image
  },
)


Future.error: When working with asynchronous code, you can use Future.error to explicitly throw an exception. This allows you to inspect the exception and handle it accordingly.

Future<void>.error('Custom error message')
    .then((_) => print('Error occurred'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Caught error: $error'));

If Anyone Knows Knows Other Method Provide Me

In Flutter, there are two ways to catch exceptions and there is a major difference between them.

To catch errors that occur on the Dart level and can be captured by Flutter, you need to use the onError method and attached a callback to it:
FlutterError.onError = (details) {
 //Logic to parse details and handle the error
};


To catch errors that are not caught by Flutter, meaning those that happen inside the native plugin that are invoked using MethodChannel, you need to use the PlatformDispatcher:
 PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
     //Logic to parse error and handle it
     //Notice you also have the stacktrace here as the second argument
 };



You can implement these two methods to call all types of errors in your Flutter application.
Be aware, that Flutter internally, when calls are invoked on the MethodChannel, wraps the execution in a try/catch block and "silences" exceptions that may occur when that code runs.
Reference

Does it Work With Particular REST API Fetch Method

@VivekYadav - Please elaborate more as your question is not clear. The logic I have shared works with exceptions generated on the Dart level and exceptions generated on the native layer.

Ok so one of the interview asked, If you are getting data from API and as always you us " try cache" method to find exception. So he asked me is their any another method to find exception when fetching data from api

Basically in easy word If I fetch data from api i didn't want to use try cache method to find exception. So , what can i do to that.

@VivekYadav - My answer explains how you can do that. If it helped you, please mark it as such.

You can use Dart's Zone to handle uncaught exceptions globally
 void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    // Handle the error
    print("Caught an error in zone: $error");
  });
}


Here is a simple example if you want to catch the error globally in Flutter
void main() async {
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    print("Caught the flutter error");
  };
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    throw Exception("Custom Error");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}

The initState throws a custom error, which will be caught by the FlutterError.onError in the main function. So, you will see "Caught the flutter error" printed in the console.
